# can build an archive for adhoc but not for app store

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5

I am able to build an archive for adhoc distruction but when I select 'Submit to the App Store', I get following pop-up.

[image]

I've read through a bunch of SO questions / answers but it seems really confusing to submit an app. Is there a way to see a log of what IS working what is NOT in this process? Or is there a common next step from this point?

thx

**edit #1**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the past, it was horrible. Recently, Apple has really improved the process. Start by going through the 2 big buttons on that notice, and follow the instructions Apple provides throughout the way.

Comment: the first one just returns me to the same screen shot and the other one is asking me for 'Enter the password used to secure the Developer Profile' - is this the same as my apple id? Sorry for stupid questions

Comment: Yes, the apple id you use to login to developer.apple.com

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a Distribution certificate in the Provisioning Portal on developer.apple.com. I had this same problem, it turned out I only had a Developer cert.

Comment: I do have a Distribution Certification. Is this what it is looking for when it queries for 'Download Identities'?

Comment: yea. you can also check your certificates in the Xcode organizer.

Comment: I've added the screenshot for the identities. Does this correspond to the certificates?

Comment: Yes, so you should be good there. I just can't remember what else I may have done to fix this. I think I just removed all of my provisioning certificates and started over following apple's directions.

Answer (score 0):

so the issue was the Bundle Identifier in ***-info.plist needed to be exactly (including case) as the provisioning profile. For a system like this, it needs better feedback.